# Objects are not valid as a React child, rendering a single number

Tags: reactjs

**SOLVED**

*Promises, Arrays and Objects can not be rendered in plain state in react. In my case, my function was returning a promise since it was set to async on accident.*

```
<h3 className="orderColorFont">Tokens: {this.tokenDecimals(this.state.order1Num[0])}</h3>
```

Trying to render a single number, not an array or an object so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

```
tokenDecimals = async (value) => {
        var add = String(value).length + Number(this.state.decimals);
        var amount = Number(String(this.state.depositsWithdrawls).padEnd(add, 0));
        return String(amount);
    }
```

This is the function returning the number. Error mentioned here thanks to comment.

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in h3 (at exchange.js:1063)
    in div (created by GridColumn)
    in GridColumn (at exchange.js:1062)
    in div (created by GridRow)
    in GridRow (at exchange.js:1055)
    in Suspense (at exchange.js:1053)
    in div (created by Grid)
    in Grid (at exchange.js:1052)
    in div (created by GridColumn)
    in GridColumn (at exchange.js:1047)
```

Comment: please mention the error as well.

Comment: tokenDecimals returns a promise.remove the `async` notation unless it has async flow inside then set state.

Comment: why tokenDecimals is an async function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tokenDecimals is an async function and it'll return a Promise which is an Object. In your case it looks there's no need to make tokenDecimals async so just simply removing async should be fine.

```
tokenDecimals = (value) => {
  var add = String(value).length + Number(this.state.decimals);
  var amount = Number(String(this.state.depositsWithdrawls).padEnd(add, 0));
  return String(amount);
}
```

More reading about async function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function